# Why does compiling rust-crypto lead to a stack overflow?

Tags: rust, rust-crypto

I'm trying to compile rust-crypto on Mac OS 10.10. I set my stack size at the hard limit of 65532 KB, but I get a stack overflow error:

```
sh-3.2$ cargo build --verbose                                                       

Compiling rust-crypto v0.2.36                                                                                               
Running `rustc --crate-name crypto /Users/adminuser/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/rust-crypto-0.2.36/src/lib.rs --color always --crate-type lib --emit=dep-info,link -C debuginfo=2 -C metadata=532b3e4fff823a9b -C extra-filename=-532b3e4fff823a9b --out-dir /Users/adminuser/abc/target/debug/deps -L dependency=/Users/adminuser/abc/target/debug/deps --extern libc=/Users/adminuser/abc/target/debug/deps/liblibc-3ffb3aaa3935201b.rlib --extern rand=/Users/adminuser/abc/target/debug/deps/librand-59170c5140920682.rlib --extern rustc_serialize=/Users/adminuser/abc/target/debug/deps/librustc_serialize-05a36c10a732afd3.rlib --extern time=/Users/adminuser/abc/target/debug/deps/libtime-d920778de8a0916a.rlib --cap-lints allow -L native=/Users/adminuser/abc/target/debug/build/rust-crypto-6abe0ddd90a37e77/out -l static=_rust_crypto_helpers`                                    

thread 'main' has overflowed its stack                                          
fatal runtime error: stack overflow                                             
error: Could not compile `rust-crypto`.                                         

Caused by:
  process didn't exit successfully: `rustc --crate-name crypto /Users/adminuser/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/rust-crypto-0.2.36/src/lib.rs --color always --crate-type lib --emit=dep-info,link -C debuginfo=2 -C metadata=532b3e4fff823a9b -C extra-filename=-532b3e4fff823a9b --out-dir /Users/adminuser/abc/target/debug/deps -L dependency=/Users/adminuser/abc/target/debug/deps --extern libc=/Users/adminuser/abc/target/debug/deps/liblibc-3ffb3aaa3935201b.rlib --extern rand=/Users/adminuser/abc/target/debug/deps/librand-59170c5140920682.rlib --extern rustc_serialize=/Users/adminuser/abc/target/debug/deps/librustc_serialize-05a36c10a732afd3.rlib --extern time=/Users/adminuser/abc/target/debug/deps/libtime-d920778de8a0916a.rlib --cap-lints allow -L native=/Users/adminuser/abc/target/debug/build/rust-crypto-6abe0ddd90a37e77/out -l static=_rust_crypto_helpers` (signal: 6, SIGABRT: process abort signal)
```

Comment: Can not reproduce on macOS 10.14.1 / Rust 1.30.0.

Comment: Post `rustc --version` and `cargo --version` at the least.

Comment: If the stack is too small, how about trying a bigger one? On Linux, the stack size can be increased with `ulimit -s`; not sure whether this works on OSX as well.

Comment: `rustc --version
rustc 1.30.1 (1433507eb 2018-11-07)
cargo --version
cargo 1.30.0 (a1a4ad372 2018-11-02)`

I increased ulimit to max, including stack size to 65532 kb.

Comment: @Jeff, have you tried nightly? `rustup install nightly; cargo +nightly build`

Comment: @hellow, Just tried nightly but doesnt help :(